# Google map in a tab created with angularjs is not centered

Tags: google-maps, angularjs, tags

I have the following problem:

I'm working in an aplication to book hotels that has tabs ("Hotel Details", "Map", "Reviews") in the overview page. the tabs are created with angularjs.
also, in the page I have the hotel address that is a link to the "Map" tab.
When I click on the "Map" tab, the google map is rendering ok. But, when I click on the hotel address, the "Map" tab opens but the map is not centered. If I refresh the page, it appears centered.

this is the code that process the map:

```
$scope.loadMap = function (targetID){
            var latitude = $scope.latitude;     
            var longitude = $scope.longitude;
            if(latitude && longitude && document.getElementById(targetID) != null ){
                var center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                var map_options = {
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: center,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                // create map
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(targetID), map_options);

                // configure marker
                var marker_options = {
                    map: map,
                    position: center,
                    title: $scope.hotelName
                };

                // create marker
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker(marker_options);

                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                },2000);
            }
        }
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle (or equivalent)? Also, you should look into using the `$window`, `$timeout`, and `$document` services.

Comment: Hi, you really should'nt refer to HTML elements from your scope... it will lead to memory leaks and is generally a bad approach for Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this very problem when I was creating maps using [`Leaflet.js`](http://leafletjs.com/).  I was trying to initialize the map inside of my angular service and it was loading very strangely.  It appears you are trying to do the same thing, but you're doing it inside of your controller, rather than a service, but the effect is the same thing.

The problem is timing.  Your controller is run before the DOM finishes loading and before angular has a chance to scan through the DOM to build out your Map page partial.  Because of that, the page is only partially loaded when you call `$scope.loadMap`, which loads the google map, as you would expect.  The problem is that once Angular finishes scanning the DOM partial, it modifies the DOM and then loads it into the view.  When this happens, the google map has already been initialized to its default size based on the previous state of the DOM, and doesn't resize properly when angular is finished with the DOM.

Ok, that was a long explanation, but here's how you fix it:

You should do all of your map initialization inside of a directive's linking function.  You could create a directive called something like `app.directive('hotelMap')`, which would initialize your map using the `$scope.latitude` and `$scope.longitude` variables from your controller.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.latitude, scope.longitude);
    var map_options = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    // create map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(targetID), map_options);
    // configure marker
    var marker_options = {
        map: map,
        position: center,
        title: $scope.hotelName
    };
    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(marker_options);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}
```

And then in your map partial, you would have an element that looks something like `<div hotel-map></div>`.  This fixes your problem, because your map will never be initialized until Angular has finished scanning/modifying the DOM and has finished rendering your partial.  That way, the map's containing element will be at its final size/position and the map will be loaded into the element's center properly.  Give it a try and let me know if that works.